# Issue with the Python Eve TokenAuth Feature

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, eve

I am currently testing the python-eve library since a few days to create a restful API but I'm experiencing some issues when I follow this [tutorial](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html) to implement a "Token Authentication".

Here is my user schema:

```
users_schema = {
    'username': {
         'type': 'string',
         'required': True,
         'unique': True,
         },
     'password': {
         'type': 'string',
         'required': True,
     },
     'roles': {
         'type': 'list',
         'allowed': ['user', 'sudo', 'admin'],
         'required': True,
     },
     'token': {
         'type': 'string',
         'required': True,
     }
 }
```

Here is my user domain configuration:

```
users = {
    'title': 'user',
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'username'
    },
    'cache_control': '',
    'cache_expires': 0,
    'allowed_roles': ['sudo', 'admin', 'user'],
    'extra_response_fields': ['token'],
    'schema': users_schema
}
```

And here is the code I run to test my API:

```
class RolesAuth(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token,  allowed_roles, resource, method):
        users = app.data.driver.db['users']
        lookup = {'token': token}
        if allowed_roles:
            lookup['roles'] = {'$in': allowed_roles}
        user = users.find_one(lookup)
        return user

    def add_token(documents):
        for document in documents:
            document["token"] = (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(10)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve(auth=RolesAuth)
    app.on_insert_users += add_token
    app.run()
```

My problem is when I try to make a request on the users endpoint like this

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5000/users" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic <MY_TOKEN>"
```

With the  as the token actually stored in the users collection, I always got the following error:

> Please provide proper credentials

And on the API logs:

> 127.0.0.1 - [29/Jun/2014 03:12:32] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 401 -

Here is a sample of what I have in mongodb for the user's token that I use for this example:

```
{
    "username" : "cmorent",
    "password" : "<MY_PASSWORD>"
    "roles" : [
        "sudo",
        "admin",
        "user"
    ],
    "token" : "<MY_TOKEN>"
}
```

Do you guys have any idea of what I am doing wrong? Is this something wrong with the Authorization header that I send?

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you properly encoded the token being sent with your request? Basic/Token auth want it Base64-encoded. I suggest you experiment with some kind of client (like Postman in Chrome) so you can see what actually is going on and how the auth token is being encoded.

Comment: In fact, I didn't base 64 encoded it... Thanks Nicola!

Comment: Just tried it but it did I still have the 'Please provide proper creditentials' message. I tried to add some debug in my check_auth method and when I try to POST/GET something, it prints nothing. Do you see something wrong in it?

Comment: Well, my bad, everything works fine for me now. Thanks a lot again Nicola!

Comment: @NicolaIarocci I have stumbled upon the same issue. Se this SO post. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here. Pretty sure the token is Base64 encoded.

Comment: Here is the missing link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501022/401-when-trying-to-authenticate-user-in-eve-flask-framework