# 401 when trying to authenticate user in Eve flask framework

Tags: python, authentication, flask, jwt, eve

I'm using the awesome [Eve REST-framework](http://python-eve.org/index.html) for creating a CRUD API with JWT authentication. I've looked at the tutorials [posted here](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#token) but I'm receiving a 401 error when doing a POST request to my endpoints that require token auth.

I've read this SO question: [Issue with the Python Eve TokenAuth Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472439/issue-with-the-python-eve-tokenauth-feature) but I'm pretty sure the token is Base64 encoded.

This is the response I'm getting back from the server when doing a cURL GET request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: <MYTOKEN>" -i http://MY_IP/users/548f6ecd64e6d12236c9576b

---- Response ----

HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 10:49:25 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 91
Connection: keep-alive
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm:"eve"

{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "Please provide proper credentials", "code": 401}}
```

Below is my code:

**app.py**

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import TokenAuth

import jwt


class RolesAuth(TokenAuth):

    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        users = app.data.driver.db['users']
        # Add check of user credentials by decoding JWT
        user = users.find_one({'token': token})
        return user


def add_token(documents):
    for document in documents:
        payload = {'username': document['username']}
        document["token"] = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve(auth=RolesAuth)
    app.on_insert_users += add_token
    app.run()
```

**settings.py**

```
users_schema = {
    'username': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'password': {
        'type': 'string',
        'required': True,
    },
    'email': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 200,
        'required': True,
    },
    'token': {
        'type': 'string',
    },
    'created': {
        'type': 'datetime',
    }
}

users = {
    'cache_control': '',
    'cache_expires': 0,
    'extra_response_fields': ['token'],
    'public_methods': ['POST'],
    'schema': users_schema
}

DOMAIN = {
    'users': users,
}
```

I have a token stored in my MongoDB for the user and I'm making the request with [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) and I'm including the token in the Authorization header like so:

```
Authorization: <USERTOKEN>
```

Any thoughts on why this gives me a 401.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code but, for simplicity, I got rid of `jwt.encode`:

```
def add_token(documents):
    for document in documents:
        payload = {'username': document['username']}
        document["token"] = 'hello'
```

I POSTed a new user to `/users` and then did a GET to the same endpoint with Postman: it works like a charm (`200`). Then I did the same test with `curl`:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic Y2lhbzo=" -i http://localhost:5000/users
```

That also retuns a `200`. As you can see the Auth header is encoded (copy & paste from Postman request preview). Just make sure you are passing the right stuff, maybe set a breakpoint in `check_auth` to validate what's coming into it and wether the db lookup is successful or not.

Hope this helps in diagnosing your issue.

PS: please note that in curl the Authorization header also has a `Basic` statement before the token, which seems to be lacking in your code snippet.

**UPDATE**

For the sake of it I also installed PyJWT and tested your code and... it works just fine on my end. Must be something wrong with your request.

**UPDATE2**

One thing that might not be so obvious is that you still need to append an (encoded) `:` to your auth header (it's Basic Auth and it parses both username and pw). That's why in the above example you have a `=` at the end of the encoded 'hello'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So basically the Auth service decodes the token I send in my Authorization header?

Comment: Could you also post the implementation you did of PyJWT. Not sure I'm doing it the right way. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now. It's solved :) Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: I think @nicola-iarocci meant was to use `:` not `;` so the string to encode would be `"hello:"`

Comment: @HenriqueB. Thanks for pointing this out. I edited Nicola's answer and changed the `;` to `:`.